# How to print string in same line without leaving space?

Tags: javascript

I created function with switch case using javascript.  I used for loop to print desired output.

```
function convert (x){
    switch(x) {
       case "c":
         return "d";
       case "a":
         return "o";
       case "t": 
         return "g";
      }
}
var str = "cat";
for (i = 0; i< str.length; i++){
   console.log(convert(str[i]));
}
```

My output is

> d
>      o
>      g

But I want output in same line without space as

> dog

Comment: I want output on a browser as well as Node.js

Answer (score 2):

The snippet below

1. [spreads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the characters of the string into an array;
2. [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) every character in the array using your `convert()` function;
3. [joins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the characters back together into a string.

The result of that operation is then passed to `console.log()` to be printed in one line.

```js
function convert(x) {
  switch (x) {
    case "c":
      return "d";
    case "a":
      return "o";
    case "t":
      return "g";
  }
}

var str = "cat";

console.log([...str].map(convert).join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` always writes complete lines. If you want to use `console.log` to output `"dog"` in your case, you have to build the string and then output it in one call.

With minimal changes to your code:

```js
function convert(x) {
  switch (x) {
    case "c":
      return "d";
    case "a":
      return "o";
    case "t":
      return "g";
  }
}
var str = "cat";
var result = "";
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  result += convert(str[i]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `.replace` instead, and a replacement object rather than `switch`, for DRY code:

```js
const replacements = {
  c: 'd',
  a: 'o',
  t: 'g'
};
const str = "cat";
const convert = str => str.replace(/[cat]/g, char => replacements[char]);
console.log(convert(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than logging in every loop, you can save it to some string and print later

```js
function convert (x){
switch(x) {case "c": return "d"; case "a": return "o"; case "t": 
return "g"; }
}
var str = "cat", convertedStr = '';
for (i = 0; i< str.length; i++){
convertedStr += convert(str[i]);
}

console.log(convertedStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending individual character to the function send an array of characters. Run a loop over the array and then push relevant character to another array and join them

```js
function convert(x) {
  let newArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    switch (x[i]) {
      case "c":
        newArray.push("d");
        break;
      case "a":
        newArray.push("o");
        break;
      case "t":
        newArray.push("g");
        break;
    }
  }
  return newArray.join('')
}
var str = "cat";
console.log(convert(str.split('')))
```